# Error when compiling on iPhone, not iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compiler-errors, linker-errors, mach-o

This is the error message:

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/Michael/Desktop/Phattie/phattie/SpeechKit.framework/SpeechKit for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Yes, it is a dreaded Mach-O Linker error. I can't stand them. An earlier version of my app worked on my iPhone, I'm just curious as to what's going on, any help appreciated!

- Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are building your app with the armv7s architecture but the SpeechKit doesn't include such an architecture. Either get an updated version of the framework that includes armv7s or removed armv7s from the list of architectures used by your app.

Comment: Okay, That's clear, but why would it build on the simulator? Just different build settings for my iPhone?

Comment: The simulator only uses the i386 architecture. A device build uses armv7 and possibly armv7s (and used to use armv6).

Comment: well that makes sense. Could it have been an error that I accidentally downloaded the mac version of the framework? I doubt it, also, If i were to remove armv7s architecture form the app, would it break?

Comment: If you had the Mac version then it wouldn't have armv7 in it. Removing armv7s from your app's architectures just means it won't be as optimized for the newer iOS devices like the iPhone 5 but it will still work just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! you're a great help! You're very knowledgable on al this, where did you obtain this knowledge?

Comment: I had my first iOS app in the app store just a week after it opened and I've been programming since before half the posters on this site were born. In other words - lots and lots of practice.